# When does a CPU write to main memory in the absence of a volatile mechanism?

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching, concurrency, locking

Consider the following C# code in a multi-core/multiprocessor environment running on x64 or ARM:

```
public sealed class Trio
{
    public long A;
    public long B;
    public long C;
}

public static class MP
{
    private static readonly object locker = new object();
    private static readonly Trio Data = new Trio();

    public static Trio ReadCopy()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            return new Trio { A = Data.A, B = Data.B, C = Data.C };
        }
    }

    public static void Set(long a, long b, long c)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            Data.A = a;
            Data.B = b;
            Data.C = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Synchronization of threads is obviously clearly handled.

However, I have a question based on the following observations as per my understanding:

1. The `lock` statement guarantees that a) only one thread can access `Data` and b) the fields in `Data` will never be "torn".
2. `Lock` provides a memory barrier, which won't have any noticeable effect in these two contexts as far as I can see.
3. Since the fields are not marked `volatile` and since there are no `Volatile.Read()` and `Volatile.Write()` operations, the three fields will be written to cache, not directly to main memory.
4. The only way to write directly to main memory is through one of the aforementioned "volatile" mechanisms as these use `ref` operations and disable optimizations, resulting in a main memory read/write.
5. Looking at the code, the CPU will, at some point unknown to me, write those fields to main memory.
6. I don't see why multiple threads are guaranteed to see the latest version of the three fields, especially on a weakly ordered memory architecture such as ARM.

My question is: how can I be sure that a call to `ReadCopy()` after a call to `Set()` is going to see the latest values for the three fields? The calling thread could be on a different core and have its own cached copies of `Data`.

"Volatile" mechanisms obviously exist for a reason. The example usually revolve around accessing non-locked memory segments. But, what of the example here? I've never seen code that uses a `lock` **and** uses a volatile mechanism.

Comment: You said, "2. `Lock` provides a memory barrier..." Why do you think that memory barrier is not sufficient to guarantee that `ReadCopy()` will return whatever values were provided by the most recent `Set(...)` call? (I'm not a C# programmer, but locks/mutexes/whatever-you-call-them provide that guarantee in every _other_ programming language that I have used.)

Comment: https://afana.me/archive/2015/07/10/memory-barriers-in-dot-net.aspx/

Comment: I'm not aware of the fact that a memory barrier is going to write ALL outstanding cache line to main memory. AFAIK, a memory barrier has to do with preventing reordering, not writing to main memory.

Comment: The _Java_ language promises this: Whatever assignments thread A did before it released some lock, L, will be visible to thread B _after_ thread B locks the same lock L. That's a memory barrier. That limits the ability of the hardware to re-order fetches and stores made by threads A and B. Notice that "cache" and "main memory" aren't mentioned. Those words do not appear _anywhere_ in the formal specification of the Java language. Like I said, I don't know C#, but C# was inspired by Java. I bet you can understand how C# works without ever needing to think about "cache" or "main memory."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the article [C# - The C# Memory Model in Theory and Practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice) by Igor Ostrovsky:

> When a locked block of code executes, it’s guaranteed to see all writes from blocks that precede the block in the sequential order of the lock. Also, it’s guaranteed not to see any of the writes from blocks that follow it in the sequential order of the lock.
>
> In short, locks hide all of the unpredictability and complexity weirdness of the memory model: You don’t have to worry about the reordering of memory operations if you use locks correctly.

I think this answers your question quite thoroughly!

There is also a part 2: [C# - The C# Memory Model in Theory and Practice, Part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/january/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice-part-2)